# how to write clean try/catch block when find function returns a reference?

Tags: c++, reference, try-catch

I have some code that looks like this:

```
const SomeType & elt = x.find();
try {
    // ... do something with elt ...
} catch (...) {
    // handle processing exception
}
```

And it works, but due to changing circumstances, it's now possible for that `find()` method to throw a "not found" exception, which I need to catch.

What I'd like to write would be

```
try {
    const SomeType & elt = x.find();
} catch (...) {
    // handle "not found" exception
    return;
}
try {
    // ... do something with elt ...
} catch (...) {
    // handle processing exception
}
```

But of course this doesn't work, because `elt` is no longer in scope by the time its processing block is reached.  I can't rearrange this to

```
const SomeType & elt;
try {
    elt = x.find();
} catch (...) {
    // handle "not found" exception
    return;
}
```

because of course reference types in C++ aren't allowed to be uninitialized.  So I'm left with the options of temporarily setting `elt` to be a reference to a dummy object of type `SomeType`, which I'd rather not do, or nesting the try/catch blocks, like this:

```
try {
    const SomeType & elt = x.find();
    try {
        // ... do something with elt ...
    } catch (...) {
        // handle processing exception
    }
} catch (...) {
    // handle "not found" exception
}
```

I don't like this, either: the nesting is confusing, and I don't like the way the "not found" exception handler is hiding down there at the end.

Can anyone think of a better way to arrange this?  (In C, of course, we'd just have the `find` function return a null pointer in the not-found case, and handle it that way, but I like to try not to be an old C programmer when I'm writing C++, and anyway `x.find()` is already set up to return a reference, not a pointer.)

Comment: And this is why I hate find functions that exit via exception when not found.  If the function instead returned a `std::pair<bool, pointer_to_object>` then you could capture that with a structured binding and then your not found check would be an if statement right after you call `find`.  Do you have any control over the interface of `find`?

Comment: Since it is logically impossible to " // ... do something with elt ..." if `find()` throws an exception, whichever way you wish to handle that exception must, therefore, be logically different from what your existing try/catch does, before resuming with the rest of the code that does use the reference. Therefore you simply need another try/catch block around ***that*** to do whatever cleanup needs to be done if `find()` throws an exception.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't like 'em either.  I do have control over the rest of the code, although I'm not sure I'll choose to exercise it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If exceptions are different, you might use the same try block:

```
try {
    const SomeType& elt = x.find();
    // ... do something with elt ...
} catch (const NotFoundException&) {
    // handle "not found" exception
} catch (...) {
    // handle processing exception
}
```

else rebinding reference is not allowed, but might be simulated by pointer or `std::reference_wrapper` in general,

And optional reference (not allowed neither in std, but boost allow it) might be simulated by pointer or `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>`.

So:

```
const SomeType* eltPtr = nullptr; 
try {
    eltPtr = &x.find();
} catch (const NotFoundException&) {
    // handle "not found" exception
    return;
}
const SomeType& elt = *eltPtr; 
try {
    // ... do something with elt ...
} catch (...) {
    // handle processing exception
}
```

Comment: Yes.  The first part of your answer is the right solution, I think.  I can't use it directly (because, alas the exceptions are *not* different), but they *should* be.

Comment: The pointer solution I had already alluded to in the question, and discarded.

Comment: @SteveSummit "*alas the exceptions are not different*" - then how would you differentiate between them to begin with? Do they have any *member data* that is different depending on the circumstance?

Comment: @SteveSummit: owning pointers are bad, non-owning pointers are fine (not necessary the best way)

Comment: @RemyLebeau With the exceptions structured as they currently are, the only way to differentiate them is with distinct try/catch blocks, one encompassing the search code and a second encompassing the processing.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point.  I may yet switch to pointers in this case.  For now (although it's irrelevant to the question as stated) I've discovered that besides `find()`, object `x` also has a Boolean `isPresent()` method that I can call first, to predict whether the find will succeed.  TMTOWTDI.

Comment: Require two look-up though :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 And race conditions if it were multithreaded!  But for the moment it's a prototype (and single-threded), so I'm not going to obsess *too* much over either style or efficiency.  (Probably spent considerably more time than it was worth by dragging SO in at all.  But I appreciate the insights.)

Comment: multithread would be an extra issue if the class were already thread safe, which is not (how to unsure reference validity?).

Answer (score 1):

Split into another function:

```
void func1()
{
    try {
        const SomeType & elt = x.find();
        func2(elt);
    } catch (...) {
        // handle "not found" exception
    }
}

void funct2(const SomeType & elt)
{
    try {
        // ... do something with elt ...
    } catch (...) {
        // handle processing exception
    }
}
```

Though in general I find your interface slightly disturbing to require all these try/catch blocks in the first place. Unfortunately it is hard to offer advice on how to improve the general style with such little information.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I don't think I'll use it (there's no good name for the second function, and the control flow ends up being as confusing as the nested try/catch blocks), but you're right, in general it's a classic technique to reduce objectionable nesting by breaking something out to a function.

Comment: @SteveSummit Why is the processing of exceptional stuff not handeled by destructors?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is "Because neither I nor this legacy codebase have really wrapped our heads around RAII."

Answer (score 1):

It will not be to everyone's taste (the behaviour *is* defined by the way), but you could use

```
#include <functional>
std::reference_wrapper<const SomeType> elt = elt;
try {
    elt = x.find();
} catch (...) {
    // handle "not found" exception
    return;
}
```

Arguably the setting of `elt` to itself is an abuse of `std::reference_wrapper`, which has its default and move constructors deleted by design: I'm circumventing that.

Essentially `std::refernce_wrapper` is a pointer under the hood but you can rebind it, which is essentially what you want to do here.

Comment: I would never have thought of this!  I certainly agree about it being "not to everyone's taste" (indeed in this case I'd say it's a cure that's worse than the disease), but I'm glad to know of the technique, so thanks for posting.

Comment: Are you sure self initialization is valid? (member should be copied, so reading uninitialized value -> UB, as `int n = n;`).